# Paypal Express Checkout: It is possible set recipient with ActiveMerchant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, activemerchant

I'm using ActiveMerchant and Paypal Express Checkout payment. It is possible to set recipient? For example:

```
gateway =  ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(
  :login => "...",
  :password => "...",
  :signature => "..."
)

response = gateway.setup_purchase(100,
  ip: request.remote_ip,
  return_url: 'http://localhost:3000/cancel',
  cancel_return_url: 'http://localhost:3000/return',
  recipient: 'seller@example.com' # Set recipient here
)

redirect_to gateway.redirect_url_for(response.token)
```

Answer (score -1):

What do yo mean by recipient? You are setting the gateway to direct all the payment to the owner of those credentials.